# Can I do that with PayPal?

Tags: paypal

I'm managing several companies and would like to issue PayPal invoices and get all of my information organized in a central location…  I couldn't find how to do that at PayPal. Can anyone help?

I would like to send PayPal invoice to my customers and allow them to make partial payments. Can I do that with PayPal?

Comment: The short answer is yes, you can do anything you need to with PayPal for the most part.  There are a number of products that can be used to achieve this goal, though, and depending on many details one route may be better than another route.  This sort of thing is a little too broad for this forum, but if you want to [contact me directly](http://www.angelleye.com/quote-request/) I can help you get this done.

Answer (score 0):

I am back with my answer ..please see below what i got ?
It doesn't look like they have a real solution for this: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Merchant-services-Archive/Multiple-businesses-with-one-account/td-p/211740 but this seems like a viable option: http://www.billiving.com/Signup/PayPal